# REGEX finding strings within a string

Tags: c#, regex

I seem to write one Reg expression a year and always end up asking for help.

Here's a string (it's a search string from Solr) and I want to select every instance of the search word.

Here's the input:-

```
http://server:8080/solr/app/select?q=(title_st_en%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ar%3Atheory+OR+title_st_da%3Atheory+OR+title_st_fr%3Atheory+OR+title_st_de%3Atheory+OR+title_st_it%3Atheory+OR+title_st_no%3Atheory+OR+title_st_sv%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ru%3Atheory+OR+title_st_es%3Atheory+OR+title_st_bg%3Atheory+OR+title_st_cs%3Atheory+OR+title_st_tr%3Atheory+OR+title_st_nl%3Atheory+OR+title_st_zh-cn%3Atheory+OR+title_st_zh-tw%3Atheory+OR+title_st_hr%3Atheory+OR+title_st_et%3Atheory+OR+title_st_he%3Atheory+OR+title_st_hu%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ja%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ko%3Atheory+OR+title_st_pl%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ro%3Atheory+OR+title_st_th%3Atheory+OR+title_st_vi%3Atheory+OR+content_stemming_en%3Atheory+OR+content_stemming_no%3Atheory+OR+(backfields%3Atheory))+AND+(((virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CU_TEST%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_SYSTEM%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_!CONTACTS%22)+AND+-(virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CU_TEST%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_SYSTEM%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NDSF%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NDSFMAG%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NDSFRA%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NM%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_INTERNAL%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A
```

I need to select any text between every '`%3A`' and '`+OR`' as well as the final '`%3Atheory`))' - in this case the word '`theory`' but it will be a different word every time - the only known thing is it'll be any alpha text between the '`%3A`' and the '`+OR`'.  And it need to stop at the '`+AND+`'

I've got as far as `/%3A(.*?)[+OR]/g` - it's a start I guess... 
It doesn't find '`%3Atheory))`' and it doesn't stop at '`+AND+`'

I'm struggling with 'find this' OR 'find that' as well as stopping at a string.

anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xhEq1j/1)?

Comment: Yes!  I hadn't realised I had to escape each close bracket. Almost there - I need something to stop at the '+AND+' expression.

Comment: Like [so](https://regex101.com/r/xhEq1j/2)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be stopping at the 'AND' - I added some more input to the search string for clarity.

Comment: For which language  is it?

Comment: On regEx101 - the same site your examples are on.  Although the end destination is c#.  If you try the updated example I put up you can see the matches don't stop at 'AND' - they continue on past

Comment: Has you question been answered? If not then please [edit] it to explain what is missing. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) it might be better to split in two operations using String.Split and the Regex.Matches like so:

```
string input = @"http://server:8080/solr/app/select?q=(title_st_en%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ar%3Atheory+OR+title_st_da%3Atheory+OR+title_st_fr%3Atheory+OR+title_st_de%3Atheory+OR+title_st_it%3Atheory+OR+title_st_no%3Atheory+OR+title_st_sv%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ru%3Atheory+OR+title_st_es%3Atheory+OR+title_st_bg%3Atheory+OR+title_st_cs%3Atheory+OR+title_st_tr%3Atheory+OR+title_st_nl%3Atheory+OR+title_st_zh-cn%3Atheory+OR+title_st_zh-tw%3Atheory+OR+title_st_hr%3Atheory+OR+title_st_et%3Atheory+OR+title_st_he%3Atheory+OR+title_st_hu%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ja%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ko%3Atheory+OR+title_st_pl%3Atheory+OR+title_st_ro%3Atheory+OR+title_st_th%3Atheory+OR+title_st_vi%3Atheory+OR+content_stemming_en%3Atheory+OR+content_stemming_no%3Atheory+OR+(backfields%3Atheory))+AND+(((virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CU_TEST%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_SYSTEM%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_!CONTACTS%22)+AND+-(virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CU_TEST%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_SYSTEM%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NDSF%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NDSFMAG%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NDSFRA%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_NM%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_INTERNAL%5C%5CL%22+OR+virtualPath%3A";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"%3A(.*?)(?:\+OR|\)\))");

var splitted = input.Split(new[] { "AND" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var matches = regex.Matches(splitted.First());

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    // Or whatever you like to do with your matches
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex.Split` has an option to keep the separating strings. So for the text given in the question, code like that below will split it into pieces:

```
string[] pieces = Regex.Split(theInputText, "(%3A.*?\\+(?:AND|OR))");
foreach (string ss in pieces)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ss);
}
```

Here is a small section of the output:

```
+virtualPath
%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_SYSTEM%22+OR
+virtualPath
%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CP_!CONTACTS%22)+AND
+-(virtualPath
%3A%22%5C%5CSERVER%5C%5CU_TEST%5C%5CL%22+OR
+virtualPath
```

Having split the string into pieces it should be a simple matter to screen for the array elements with the correct starting and ending characters, also to find the last `%3Atheory...` entry.

Note: The question discusses `+OR` and `+AND+` but all the `+OR`s are followed with a `+` so it may be better to include a final `+` in the expression, as `...OR)\\+)`.

Note: The inner brackets in the regular expression are non capturing, ie `(?:  )`. If they were capturing brackets then the `AND` and `OR` captures would be included in the output array.